# Monthly values with group_concat, GROUP BY and null values

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to output each months' payments in a year with a group_concat even if there were no payment, while grouping by category. 
The `amount` is the a comma separated list of each month's total payments ordered by month.
Current output from the below query is:

```
label     amount
NULL      0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00
Food      17.90,977.25
Transport 40.00
```

I can't manage merge the NULL label with the others as well as list categories with no expenditure. I think it might be to do with the way I've joined the tables?

The intended output is:

```
label       amount
Healthcare  0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00
Food        0.00,0.00,17.90,0.00,977.25,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00
Transport   40.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00
```

My current query is:

```
select label, group_concat(payment) as amount
from(
SELECT 
categoryName as label, 
YEAR(t1.transactionDate),
t.month,
coalesce(SUM(t1.transactionAmount),0) payment
FROM
(SELECT 1 AS `month`
UNION 
SELECT 2 AS `month`
UNION  
SELECT 3 AS `month`
UNION 
 SELECT 4 AS `month`
UNION
 SELECT 5 AS `month`
UNION
 SELECT 6 AS `month`
UNION 
 SELECT 7 AS `month`
UNION 
 SELECT 8 AS `month`
UNION 
  SELECT 9 AS `month`
UNION 
  SELECT 10 AS `month`
UNION 
  SELECT 11 AS `month`
UNION 
SELECT 12 AS `month`
) AS t
LEFT JOIN transaction t1 on(t.month = MONTH(t1.transactionDate))
LEFT JOIN category USING (categoryID)
where userid = 1 or userid is null group by t.month)a group by label
```

Any help would be great as I've been wrestling with this for a while with little headway.
Thanks!

Comment: This may help. https://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/filling-missing-data-sequences-cardinal-integers/ It's not a tremendously easy problem to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the key is using a cartesian join on category and month. I haven't tested this, but it must be close to the solution:

```
select label, group_concat(monthly_sum separator ',') as amount
from (
    select c.categoryName as label, coalesce(sum(t1.payment), 0) as monthly_sum
    from category c
    join (
        SELECT 1 AS month
        UNION 
        SELECT 2 AS month
        UNION  
        SELECT 3 AS month
        UNION 
        SELECT 4 AS month
        UNION
        SELECT 5 AS month
        UNION
        SELECT 6 AS month
        UNION 
        SELECT 7 AS month
        UNION 
        SELECT 8 AS month
        UNION 
        SELECT 9 AS month
        UNION 
        SELECT 10 AS month
        UNION 
        SELECT 11 AS month
        UNION 
        SELECT 12 AS month
    ) t
    left join transaction t1 on t.month = MONTH(t1.transactionDate)
    where userid = 1 or userid is null
    group by t.month, c.categoryName
) a
group by label
```

Comment: Thank you! Selecting from category was the answer for me. While this query didn't quite work, it did help me get to the solution I needed! I did also have to add an extra qualification on: LEFT JOIN transaction t1 on(t.`month` = MONTH(t1.transactionDate)) and using(businessID)